# "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command" error when using Azure CLI

Tags: bash, cmd, git-bash, azure-cli, azure-cli2

Sometimes I have a problem with running various commands (I'm using Git Bash, if that matters). For example, when I try to execute:

```sh
az container exec --resource-group My-RG --name influxdb-container --exec-command "/bin/bash"
```

The command above should normally "SSH" me into the Azure Container Instance. However, instead, I'm getting:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

I found a lot of posts on SO with such error, however, the issue in those posts was about invoking commands without proper quoting of "C:\Program Files". In my case, however, there is no "Program Files" anywhere, so I have a hard time figuring out what is wrong.

`az` command is recognized by the shell, when I invoke it alone, I'm getting proper response from Azure CLI.

I am also getting a similar error when running docker commands sometimes. Unfortunately, right now I do not know which command exactly would cause that.

This issue happens only on my Windows machine. When I run the command from Linux or macOS, it just works.

Screenshot of the error:
[image]

And the proof that `az` works:

[image]

Comment: It probably is going to be the quoting error, but it'll be taking the unquoted string from either your environment variables or the registry I'd guess, and not handling it correctly for whatever reason. I don't have any good ideas where to start looking though. Is there any obvious config that azure-cli uses you can check for instances of C:\Program Files\ ?

Comment: @Rup I looked through `%USERPROFILE%\.azure` and didn't see anything like it.

Comment: Is `/bin/bash` a script file? (.cmd or .bat)

Comment: @avery_larry "/bin/bash" is a program that I want to run inside of my Azure Container instance

Comment: Forgive me as I'm not familiar with Azure CLI.  However, I'm trying to find out if /bin/bash is a physical file you have access to.  If it is, then I want to know if it is bash.cmd or bash.bat or bash.pl or bash.exe or bash.com or whatever.  Or you can just open the file with notepad and look in it to see if there is any unquoted "c:\program files" lines in it anywhere.

Comment: Or for that matter az may well be a script file az.bat or az.cmd that you can take a look at.

Comment: The error seems caused by a leading `/` within your command arguments. In your example above, it's `--exec-command "/bin/bash"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are some things different between Linux and Windows for Azure CLI. But still, there is some configuration that is the same. You can also set the environment variable `PATH` the same as in Linux.

In Linux, the `az` command is in the path `/usr/bin/`, and this path is also set the environment variable `PATH`. Then the `az` command can be recognized by the shell. So the same in Windows, you can also append the path of the Azure CLI in the environment variable `PATH`. The screenshot shows the configuration on my side:

[image]

Then the `az` command can also be recognized by the CMD:

[image]

But you can also use WSL in the Windows and the same experience of the Azure CLI as in Linux.

Comment: I read the question as that az ais already in the path but the problem is running `az container exec` spawns another process using a broken path.

Comment: @Rup I don't think so. Why run the Azure CLI inside the Windows container? And he also knows the `az container exec` command only supports the single command.

Comment: Yep, "az" is in the path and I am able to run it successfully. Like @Rup mentioned, I have issue with running the specific command that I pasted in my question.

Comment: @CharlesXu I don't use "Windows containers". I'm running the `az` command from wishing normal Windows 10 installation.

Comment: @Loreno Of course, that is what I said in the answer. Rup said in the container, not me. So you just need to follow the answer.

Comment: @Loreno Any more questions? Do you solve the problem? I didn't see any updates and you also didn't accept it.

Comment: @CharlesXu I have it setup same as you have. I was able to run "az" command since the beginning. The issue is with the "az container exec --resource-group My-RG --name influxdb-container --exec-command "/bin/bash"" command only.

Comment: @Loreno Do you mean only the command `az container exec` got the error in the windows cmd, others are OK? Do you set something else or change some configuration of the cmd?

Comment: @CharlesXu yes, exactly that. Nope, no custom configs.

Comment: @Loreno Can you share the screenshot of the error in the question? It's more clear to me.

Comment: @CharlesXu Added to my question.

Comment: BTW, just found out that the command works from CMD. Only from Bash it fails

Comment: @Loreno Maybe you can try to put the command `"/bin/bash -c '/bin/bash'"` append the parameter `exec-command`. I don't know why it happens on your site. Everything is ok on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue but with AWS `sam.cmd` command.
Ended up solving it by editing my environment variables -> editing the "Path" system variable and using the "short path" to this command (which doesn't have any spaces) instead of the "long path". (A nice utility called [Path Copy Copy](https://pathcopycopy.github.io/) helped with doing this.)

Changed from: `C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin` to: `C:\PROGRA~1\Amazon\AWSSAM~1\bin`

Would suspect doing something similar for the `az` command would have solved your issue. Suspect it may be something to do with Git Bash automatically putting quotes around the whole command when the path to the executable has whitespace in it.